# Updating parent component from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't rerender the parent component from the child component - I pass `componentDidMount` as props to child class, then I call it there, and expect the parent to rerender. The render function is called, but the content remains unchanged. What's wrong?

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function () { return {content: 'clean'}; },
   componentDidMount: function () {
      this.setState({content: 'changed!'});
   },
   render: function () {
      return React.createElement('div', {rerender: this.componentDidMount.bind(this)}, this.state.content);
   }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
      return React.createElement('div', {onClick: this.handleClick}, 'click me');
   },
   handleClick: function () {
      this.props.rerender();
   }
});

ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(ReactRouter.Router, {history: ReactRouter.browserHistory},
                React.createElement(ReactRouter.Route, {path: '/parent', component: Parent})
        )
, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: send a class method as prop callback to child component, the callback needs to `setState` in the parent component

Comment: But thats exacly what I did in my example

Comment: don't use the `this.componentDidMount` as an event callback :) you should create own function to handle that `rerender` in parent component.. and of course it won't chance since when the parent component mount the state will be `content: changed!` and when you handle click it will call that same function so state will be the same..

Comment: Yes, yes, I know, I just gave an example ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount()` is a lifecycle function called when the component has completed rendering.

Calling it is seeming like you are circumventing the entire rerendering process.

You should instead create your own function.

```
   changeContent: function () {
      this.setState({content: 'changed!'});
   },
```

And then pass `changeContent()` to `rerender`.

Generally, avoid passing React's LifeCycle methods around!

Answer (score 0):

To tackle all this kind of things, the guys at Facebook come up with unidirectional data flow pattern. Your child component should not know about the parent but rather it should change some sort of state (Flux, Redux, Reflux). Changes to the state will trigger rerendering of the parent component.